# How can I stop Visual Studio 2010 from auto generating controls in a template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-4.0

I'm creating a `UserControl` which contains a `ListView`. I'm declaring it as follows, I've tried other ways with the `ParseChildren` and `PersistChildren` attributes.

```
[AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.InheritanceDemand, 
    Level=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal),
AspNetHostingPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,
    Level = AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal),
Designer(typeof(ListViewItem)),
ParseChildren(false), PersistChildren(false)]
public partial class CustomListView : System.Web.UI.UserControl, IPaneControl, INamingContainer
{
```

Inside it I have the following code to set the `ItemTemplace` of the `ListView`

```
[Browsable(false),
    DefaultValue(null),
    PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
    TemplateContainer(typeof(ListViewDataItem), BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
public virtual ITemplate ItemTemplate
{
    get { return _lvChild.ItemTemplate; }
    set { _lvChild.ItemTemplate = value; }
}
```

Now inside that template on the consumer of that control I'll use

```
<ItemTemplate><asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="ShippingAddressID" Value='<%#Eval("AddressID") %>' /></ItemTemplate>
```

In Visual Studio 2008 this led to the designer file not auto-generating a `HiddenField` ShippingAddressID, but upon going to Visual Studio 2010 it does. How can I stop it from auto-generating it in 2010?

Comment: Something I've done seems to have made the issue go away, I have no idea which thing it was.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to reference it anywhere in the code-behind couldn't you just remove the "runat=server"?

Comment: I do have to reference it, and if I switch it, how would .Net know it is a server side control?

Comment: Well it wouldn't.  That's why I was asking if you needed to reference it.  How do you reference it server side if there is not an entry in the designer file?  Are you declaring it manually?

Comment: I'm using FindControl and my own implementation with a similar idea.